# Swift 3: kill the previous scene

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, scenekit, skscene

I have a scene in my game view controller but i want to kill it when the player dies. This is because when the player restarts the game the fps decreases as the previous scenes are still running. My game runs on being repetitive and so there are multiple places where functions are called every point second. This is why the fps keeps decreasing. How can i input a method to kill the scene.

Comment: I think the current scene are destroyed when you present another scene. If your fps is going down, that might mean you have a retain cycle or something. Also, are you using SpriteKit or SceneKit?

Comment: what is a retain cycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I previously used the code `removeAllChildren()` but that didn't cover it and the reason why was i needed the code `removeAllActions()` as well